# Modelmapper: How to apply custom mapping when source object is null?

Tags: java, modelmapper

Lets assume I have class `MySource`:

```
public class MySource {
    public String fieldA;
    public String fieldB;

    public MySource(String A, String B) {
       this.fieldA = A;
       this.fieldB = B;
    }
}
```

and I would like to translate it to object `MyTarget`:

```
public class MyTarget {
    public String fieldA;
    public String fieldB;
}
```

using default ModelMapper settings I can achieve it in the following way:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
MySource src = new MySource("A field", "B field");
MyTarget trg = modelMapper.map(src, MyTarget.class); //success! fields are copied
```

It can happen however, that `MySource` object will be `null`. In this case, MyTarget will be also `null`:

```
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    MySource src = null;
    MyTarget trg = modelMapper.map(src, MyTarget.class); //trg = null
```

I would like to specify custom mapping in such a way, that (pseudo code):

`MySource src != null ? [perform default mapping] : [return new MyTarget()]`

Does anybody have idea how to write an appropriate converter to achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible using ModelMapper directly because [ModelMapper](https://github.com/jhalterman/modelmapper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/modelmapper/ModelMapper.java) `map(Source, Destination)` method checks if source is null, in that case it throws an exception...

Take a look to ModelMapper Map method implementation:

```
public <D> D map(Object source, Class<D> destinationType) {
    Assert.notNull(source, "source"); -> //IllegalArgument Exception
    Assert.notNull(destinationType, "destinationType");
    return mapInternal(source, null, destinationType, null);
  }
```

### Solution

I propose extends ModelMapper class and override `map(Object source, Class<D> destinationType)` like this:

```
public class MyCustomizedMapper extends ModelMapper{

    @Override
    public <D> D map(Object source, Class<D> destinationType) {
        Object tmpSource = source;
        if(source == null){
            tmpSource = new Object();
        }

        return super.map(tmpSource, destinationType);
    }
}
```

It checks if source is null, in that case it initializes then it calls super `map(Object source, Class<D> destinationType)`.

Finally, you could use your customized mapper like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    //Your customized mapper
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new MyCustomizedMapper();

    MySource src = null;
    MyTarget trg = modelMapper.map(src, MyTarget.class); //trg = null
    System.out.println(trg);
}
```

The output would be a `new MyTarget()`:

> Output Console:
>   NullExampleMain.MyTarget(fieldA=null, fieldB=null)

Thus it is initialized.