# modelmapper null value skip

Tags: java, null, modelmapper

```
Class A {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private B innerObject;
}
Class B {
    private String c;
}
```

In my case, String b might come in with a null value. My modelmapper configuration is like below:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration()
    .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
    .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE)
    .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    .setSkipNullEnabled(true)
    .setSourceNamingConvention(NamingConventions.JAVABEANS_MUTATOR);
```

when I map the object, I get the target object with b=null value.

Trying to stay away from a strategy shown here: [SO- Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451025/how-to-exclude-whole-property-if-they-are-null-from-modelmapper)

What am I missing?

Comment: `.setSkipNullEnabled(true)` is enough, can you show me an example of your mapping?

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried this configuration:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd rather in this way:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);

        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I make this work for only one specific mapping? Only when mapping class `A` to class `B`, I want this to be enabled.

Comment: @ShubhamDhingra you can check this [code](https://github.com/felipealvesgnu/ala-api/blob/master/src/main/java/br/org/ala/api/mapper/AssociadoMapper.java), where there some mappings handling specific situations to DTO Objects .

Answer (score 1):

Looks, like it's not possible.

```
public <D> D map(Object source, Class<D> destinationType) {
    Assert.notNull(source, "source");
    Assert.notNull(destinationType, "destinationType");
    return this.mapInternal(source, (Object)null, destinationType (String)null);
}
```

I solved it with next wrapper function.

```
private static <D> D map(Object source, Type destination) {
    return source == null ? null : mapper.map(source, destination);
}
```

Check this question too [Modelmapper: How to apply custom mapping when source object is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971193/modelmapper-how-to-apply-custom-mapping-when-source-object-is-null)