# Getting nulls while using ModelMapper

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, modelmapper

I'm trying to utilize the `ModelMapper` in my convertion process. What I need to do is to convert the `Sample` entity to `SampleDTO` object.

I have the `Sample` entity like the following:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample", schema = "sample_schema")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Sample {

    private static final String SEQUENCE = "SAMPLE_SEQUENCE";

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = SEQUENCE, name = SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_deetails")
    private Details details;
}
```

Which holds the `Details` one:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "details", schema = "sample_schema")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Details {

    private static final String SEQUENCE = "DETAILS_SEQUENCE";

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = SEQUENCE, name = SEQUENCE, allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "street_name")
    private String streetName;

    @Column
    private String city;
}
```

I'd like the DTO to be this format:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SampleDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String streetName;
    private String city;
}
```

I also made a ModelMapper bean like:

```java
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
```

And I made a converter component:

```java
@Component
public class EntityDtoConverter {

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @Autowired
    public EntityDtoConverter(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    public SampleDTO sampleToDto(Sample entity) {
        return modelMapper.map(entity, SampleDTO.class);
    }
}
```

#### **The problem is**

when I try to use this mapper converter in my service

```java
@Service
public class SampleService {

    private final SampleRepository sampleRepository;
    private final EntityDtoConverter entityDtoConverter;
    
    @Autowired
    public SampleService(SampleRepository sampleRepository, EntityDtoConverter entityDtoConverter) {
        this.sampleRepository = sampleRepository;
        this.entityDtoConverter = entityDtoConverter;
    }

    public List<SampleDTO> getSamples() {
        List<SampleDTO> samples = sampleRepository.findAll()
                .map(entityDtoConverter::sampleToDto);
        return new List<SampleDTO>(samplesPage);
    }
}
```

I get nulls in places of `Details` fields.

I have followed [Baeldung's tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application) about model-to-dto conversion with ModelMapper and the [documentation](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/) of it as well but the least wasn't much of help. There is something I'm missing and I have no idea what it is.

I'm working on:

- Java 11
- Spring Boot 2.3.0
- ModelMapper 2.3.8

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration().setPropertyCondition(Conditions.isNotNull());
```

Also check: [Modelmapper: How to apply custom mapping when source object is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971193/modelmapper-how-to-apply-custom-mapping-when-source-object-is-null)